# ExtJs submit menubutton values

Tags: button, extjs, drop-down-menu, submit

I am trying to submit the values from the menu buttons but know this is not possible and that I have to create a hidden field and store the button values there.

Being new to ExtJs I can not seem to figure out how to do this. Below is the basic layout I used to check the button shows and I can choose a colour.

```
getFormItems : function() {
    var me = this;

    return [{
        xtype    : "fieldset",
        title    : "Items to monitor",
        defaults : {
            labelSeparator : ""
        },
        items : [{
            xtype      : "checkbox",
            name       : "cpuenable",
            boxLabel   : _("Will monitor CPU Temperature"),
            fieldLabel : _("CPU Temperature"),
            checked    : false
        },{
            xtype : 'hiddenfield',
            id    : 'buttonvalues'
        },{
            xtype   : "button",
            name    : "colours",
            text    : _("Choose Colours"),
            scope   : this,
            style   : {
                marginTop       : "10px",
                marginBottom    : "10px"
            },
            menu: [{
            text: "Main CPU Colour",
            menu: {
                xtype  : "colormenu",
                name   : "colourc",
                value  : "000000",
                cls    : "menubutton-class",
                handler: function (obj, rgb) {
                    var colourmField = this.findField('colourc');
                    colourmField.setValue(rgb.toString());
                    alert(colourmField.getValue());
                }
            }
        },{ and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is an edit for you of my previous post. I give you an example how to fetch all child components you want inside a component:

Example extjs:

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    id: 'fsButtons',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'hiddenfield',
            id: 'hiddenValues'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button'
            color: '000000'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button'
            color: '555555'
        }
    ]
}
```

Function to fill the hiddenfield:

```
function getButtonVars() {
    var buttonVars = new Array();
    //Get all components with xtype 'button' inside the fieldset with id 'fsButtons'
    Ext.Array.each(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button', Ext.getCmp('fsButtons'), function(button){
      buttonVars.push(button.color);
    });

    Ext.getCmp('hiddenValues').setValue(buttonVars.join(',')); // concats all button values to one string: '000000,555555' etc.
}
```

I hope it's clear now :)

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated the code to check if it is correct so far.

Comment: Every time I try to use the Ext.Array it stops the code from working. Is there any chance you can check the code as it is now to see if there is a mistake with it.

Comment: I am completely lost now, tried everything I can think of using the above advise but getting nowhere fast. Can Tyr or anyone else give a little more detail on how to achieve my goal.

Comment: Thanks Tyr, like I said above I am new to all this and learn from examples. I have successfully integrated the code above into my code and it works like you say but the trouble I am having now is changing the "color:" (in my code is "value:") value when a new colour is chosen, setvalue() does not seem to work.

Comment: Update your code into your question to show whats happening

Comment: Updated the code. it does not like setValue. In your example it works but it will only add the default values to the array not the user selected values. PS thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Error thrown is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined"